# Python loops: loops are identical, syntax is different, output is of different types. Why?

Tags: python-2.7, loops

x = int

```
option = { 1 : 'One',
       2 : 'Two',
       3 : 'Three',
       4 : 'Four',
       5 : 'Five',
       6 : 'Six',
       7 : 'Seven',
       8 : 'Eight',
       9 : 'Nine' }
```

# Method 1:

```
for a, b in option.items():
    if a == x:
        print b

# Output: Eight


# Method 2: (Is not identical?)

print [b for a, b in option.items() if a == x]

# Output: ['Eight']
```

What is going on here, and if I prefer the cleaner form of Method #2, how could I convert its output to a simple string?

Comment: They are not identical, you are using a list comp for the second so obviously you see the string in a list. If you want a string use `"".join( [b for a, b in option.items() if a =x])`

Comment: In Python 3.x, or using `from __future__ import print_function`, you could do e.g. `[print(b) for a, b in ...]`, but in general you shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: They are not equivalent, first loop prints dict values one by one (so each print argument is a string), second one prints list. And both options are overkills - simple `option[x]` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

While this works with method 2:

```
print([b for a, b in option.items() if a == x][0])
```

I strongly prefer method 3:

```
print(option[x])
```

Both print:

```
Eight
```